# Grab all inout value as array and display using alert

Tags: javascript

I want to grab all input value in array and display using alert. Please check codes bellow. I am trying alert by class name "check_item" but getting undefined error in alert popup. My goal is to display the values which has checked before hit "Upload" button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_item" id="check_item" class="check_item" value="1">Item 1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_item" id="check_item" class="check_item" value="2">Item 2<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_item" id="check_item" class="check_item" value="3">Item 3<br/>
    <input type="button" class="uploadExternal" value="Upload"/>

</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", ".uploadExternal", function (e) {

        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("check_item").value;
        alert(x);

        });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will return a NodeList and not an element. Also if you already have jQuery, why are you using `getElementsByClassName`? Try `$('.check_item').each(function(index, element){ alert(element.value) })`

Comment: @Rajesh Yes this can grab values but i want to put it in a array and then display also only those values which has checked

Comment: Instead of `$.each`, use `$(...).map((element) => element.value).forEach((v) => console.log(v))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using **jQuery**:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".uploadExternal", function(e) {
      var x = [];
      $(".check_item").each(function(index, item){
        x.push({
          index: index,
          value: item.value,
          checked: item.checked
        });
      });
      alert(JSON.stringify(x));
      console.log(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_item" class="check_item" value="1">Item 1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_item" class="check_item" value="2">Item 2<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_item" class="check_item" value="3">Item 3<br/>
    <input type="button" class="uploadExternal" value="Upload" />
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

If you need only the checked values then use a simple condition to filter:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".uploadExternal", function(e) {
  var x = [];
  $(".check_item").each(function(index, item) {
    if (item.checked) {
      x.push(item.value);
    }
  });
  alert(!x.length ? 'Nothing selected ' : JSON.stringify(x));
  console.log(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <form>

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="check_item" class="check_item" value="1">Item 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="check_item" class="check_item" value="2">Item 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="check_item" class="check_item" value="3">Item 3</label>
    
    <input type="button" class="uploadExternal" value="Upload"/>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No. You are already using jQuery. Why not just use `$(selector)`

Comment: Yes, this is also an option I will add it as possibility

Comment: In my opinion, if you are already using a library, using inbuilt method is like an overkill as you have to do handling to support it.

Comment: Yes but i want to get only those value in array which checkbox has checked. Not all with true false. How can i filter only checked values?

Comment: @NixLi you can put a `if` condition to filter the items check the last solution